# Erlang: Shell not returning after spawn

Tags: shell, erlang, spawn

```
-module(core_profile).

-export([start/0]).

start() ->
    register(eProfile, spawn(loop())),
    ok.

loop() ->
    receive
            {Key, Pid} -> Pid ! getKey();
            {name, Pid} -> Pid ! getName();
            {address, Pid} -> Pid ! getAddress()
    end,
    loop().
```

This is my code

when I try to start the loop from the shell i get stuck.

```
2> Pid = spawn(fun()-> a end).     
<0.39.0>
3>c(core_profile.erl).
{ok, core_profile}
4>core_profile:start().
```

shouldn't the command return ok and then give me the next command line, instead of doing nothing?

Comment: Another problem with this code - the `{Key, Pid} -> Pid ! getKey()` must be the last pattern, its more general than the other patterns and will match those as well.

Comment: yeah, copying error. Should be pKey

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you do `spawn(loop())` the `loop` function is called to evaluate a result (which will be passed on to `spawn`, so you enter the infinite loop.

Instead of calling the function you must pass the function reference by doing `spawn(fun loop/0)`.

Answer (score 0):

```
spawn(Fun) -> pid()
```

Types:
Fun = function()

Returns the pid of a new process started by the application of Fun to the empty list [].

you should write `register(eProfile, spawn( fun()-> loop() end)),`